# Inside Laravel ajax success response how to pass anchor tag with url and value to another route

Tags: laravel

**My Code inside ajax(all the code properly disaplay on table)**

```
response.forEach(function(record) {
      $('#data-body').append(
          '<tr>' +
              '<td>' + record.receipt_no + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + record.student_name + '</td>' +
              '<td>' + record.total_fees_paid + '</td>' +
              '<td><a href="' + '{{ route("delete")}}' + record.id + '" class="btn btn-success">Print Detail</a></td>'+
           '</tr>'
                  )
)};
```

**My route**

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){
 Route::get('/delete/{id?}', [admincontroller::class, 'delete'])->name('delete');
   });
```

**Now How to pass the route with value inside the ajax success response anchor tag can someone help me to pass the route through anchor with value. And how many way i pass the value with route from anchor tag without further use of ajax**

Comment: can you share your controller?

Comment: Inside the ajax response i fetch all record also the id (db field name) and now i want to pass this id to another url (delete) by anchor tag (no of anchor tag created dynamically as per no of record in db because i apply loop) So by this anchor tag i want to create a url like httt..../admin/delete/id pass by anchor tag     The function inside is simple but first its required to create url like above by get

Comment: why don't you process your data first then pass it to the ajax, you can user array_map

Answer (score 1):

```
response.forEach(function(record) {        
   var url="{{ url('admin/delete')}}"+'/'+record.id
        $('#data-body').append(
             '<tr>' +
             '<td>' + record.receipt_no + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + record.student_name + '</td>' +
             '<td>' + record.total_fees_paid + '</td>' +
             '<td><a href="' + url+ '" class="btn btn-success">PrintDetail</a></td>'+
            '</tr>'
        )
});
```

You can use URL method and then pass the required parameter in the router .

Comment: But by using name routing its doesn't create proper url like http.../admin/delete/10 but it create url like this  http.../admin/delete10 so the route doesnt get properly and through 404 error. Yes it possible that i concatenate +/+ between name route and record.id  but its not proper way to create url

Comment: var url="{{ route('delete')}}" +record.id by this the proper url not create miss / before value